# Runtime Error(NZEC) on CodeChef(Java)

Tags: java

Here is the problem https://www.codechef.com/problems/CIELAB
I keep getting Runtime Error(NZEC) on CodeChef.
It worked fine on DrJava.

```
import java.util.*;
class CodeChef1{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the range");
        int k1=s.nextInt();
        int k2=s.nextInt();
        int a,b;
        if(k1>k2){
            a=k1;
            b=k2;
        }
        else{
            a=k2;
            b=k1;
        }
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number within the range");
            int n=s.nextInt();
            if(b<n & n<a){
                System.out.println(n);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Not within range");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
s.nextInt()
```

in your code, you are assuming that there will be an int every time. What if there isn't any input or the input is not an int?

So the statement should be preceeded by a check:

```
if(s.hasNextInt()){ // this is the check
  int ... = s.nextInt();
}
else{
// decide what to do. A graceful exit or assigning some default value to your int
}
```